# MikroC: Passing pin as parameter to function

Tags: c, mikroc

I am trying to write a custom delay function in MikroC for the PIC16F882 MCU.

I want to keep checking a particular pin of MCU to see if it changed, throughout the delay function.

But the issue is, I cannot pass a pin as a parameter to a function. Is there any other way of doing the same?

The purpose of flag is to determine how long the delay should be. It would automatically be turned 0 after Timer0 overflow. I have not included that part in the code to make things simpler to understand.

My function is:

```
int flag = 0;

void delay(bit pin_to_check){
     while(flag == 1){
        if(flag == 0 || pin_to_check == 0) {
             break;
        }
     }
}

void main(){
     flag = 1;
     delay(RA3_bit);
}
```

The compile-time error I get is:

```
Parameter 'pin_to_check' must not be of bit or sbit type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot pass the `bit` or `sbit` as a parameter, you can either:

1. Avoid using the function altogether (obviously),
2. Use a preprocessor macro instead of a function,
3. pass the entire register along with the bit number to the function.

Case 3. is explained in [this thread](http://forum.mikroe.com/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=26289#p131517), and would be something like:

```
void delay(unsigned char *PORT, unsigned char bitNo) {
    unsigned char bitMask = 0x01 << bitNo;
    while (flag == 1 && ((*PORT) & bitMask) != 0)
    { }
}

// delay until bit 3 is set
delay(&PORTA, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/accessing_individual_bits.htm#bit

It says bit cannot be used for argument lists.  You need to pass the register name in.

Comment: How can I do this? Can you please elaborate? What will be the register name datatype?